# Test exercise with Spanish deck and coin toss: Is my reasoning correct?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, self-learning

[image]

From a Spanish deck of 40 cards, 1 is taken:

- If gold or cup appears, 2 coins are thrown;
- If sword appears, 1 coin is thrown;
- If club appears, no coins are thrown.

---

1. **What is the probability that a face appears?**
2. **What is the probability that a gold appears and no face appears?**
3. **What is the probability that 2 faces appears?**

---

Being,

$G$: "The card is gold", $C$: "The card is club", $S$: "The card is sword", $D$: "The card is cup" and,

$F$ :"Face appears", $N$: "Number appears":

$\mathcal{P}(G)=\mathcal{P}(C)=\mathcal{P}(S)=\mathcal{P}(D)=1/4$

$\mathcal{P}(F)=\mathcal{P}(N)=1/2$

**1.**

**This is correct?**

$\mathcal{P}([(G\cap F\cap F)\cup(G\cap F\cap N)\cup (G\cap N\cap F)]$

$\cup[(D\cap F\cap F)\cup(D\cap F\cap N)\cup(D\cap N\cap F)]\cup(S\cap F))$=

$\mathcal{P}(G)\times\mathcal{P}(F)\times\mathcal{P}(F)+
\mathcal{P}(G)\times\mathcal{P}(F)\times\mathcal{P}(N)+
\mathcal{P}(G)\times\mathcal{P}(N)\times\mathcal{P}(F)+$

$\mathcal{P}(D)\times\mathcal{P}(F)\times\mathcal{P}(F)+
\mathcal{P}(D)\times\mathcal{P}(F)\times\mathcal{P}(N)+
\mathcal{P}(D)\times\mathcal{P}(N)\times\mathcal{P}(F)+
\mathcal{P}(S)\times\mathcal{P}(F)=0.5$

**Could a similar reasoning be applied for the rest of the exercise?** Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the purpose of the $\mathcal{P}(S) \times \mathcal{P}(N)$ term?  What outcome do you want to account for?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi It was in error.

Comment: I see you fixed the other two small errors too.  Your result is now correct.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi What about reasoning? Is it also correct? Thank you.

Comment: It's correct.  It's based on decomposing the event whose probability must be computed into the union of disjoint events and then adding the probabilities of all those events.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier in my opinion for the first question to ask "*What is the probability of no heads being thrown*"

No heads occur when either throwing only tails when asked to throw a coin, or when not even being given the opportunity to throw any coins.

- Clubs are drawn: no coins thrown.  Occurs with probability $\frac{1}{4}$
- Sword is drawn: the one coin comes up tails.  Occurs with probability $\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}$
- Gold or Cup is drawn: the two coins both come up tails.  Occurs with probability $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}$

Thus, probability of no heads occurring is $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{2}$, verifying your result.